# ASP.NET issue when removing Control on Page Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following Index.aspx web form:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProblematicWebApplication.Index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <asp:Label ID="dummyLabel" runat="server" Text="This is dummy label." />
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="intDropDownList" runat="server"/>
        <br />
        <asp:Button Text="Submit" OnClick="OnSubmitClicked" runat="server"/>
        <br />
        Selected value: <asp:Label ID="selectedValueLabel" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And following code behind Index.aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ProblematicWebApplication
{
    public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                this.intDropDownList.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(0, 11).ToArray();
                this.intDropDownList.DataBind();
            }

            if (this.Request["remove-dummy"] != null)
                this.Controls.Remove(this.dummyLabel);
        }

        protected void OnSubmitClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.selectedValueLabel.Text = this.intDropDownList.SelectedValue;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my application with no remove-dummy parameter in query string and select some value from intDropDownList and click Submit button, selected value is accordingly presented in selectedValueLabel.

But if I run my application with remove-dummy=1 parameter in query string, dummyLabel gets removed. Now when I select some value from intDropDownList and click Submit button, selected value is not correctly written to selectedValueLabel and all items from intDropDownList are removed.

Can someone explain it to me why this is happening?
Why removing unrelated dummyLabel control has influence on intDropDownList control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that ViewState loading fails in postback after dummyLabel is removed in previous page load.

Details:

first study following articles:

- [TRULY Understanding ViewState - Infinities Loop](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Following image shows important ASP.NET page events and where in between ViewState handling takes place.

[image: ASP.NET Page events and ViewState handling]

So what happens when declarative Control dummyLabel is removed? Here is a process:

1. Page is requested for the first time with query string parameter remove-dummy=1.
2. In Page_Load event declarative Control dummyLabel is removed.
3. Before SaveStateComplete event, ViewState is saved. There is no control dummyLabel in control tree, so its ViewState won't be saved.
4. Submit button is clicked.
5. Between InitComplete and PreLoad events, ViewState gets loaded. This is where it breaks because control tree now contains dummyLabel (dummyLabel gets removed after, in Load event) and **ASP.NET fails in recursively loading ViewState into Page control tree**. My assumption is that ViewState and Page control tree are tightly coupled and recursive ViewState loading fails as a consequence of this tight coupling.

One more situation that backs-up this theory: if you place dummyLabel at the very end of the page, issue doesn't happen anymore, because all other controls in Page control tree that come before dummyLabel already picked correct values from ViewState (ViewState structure and Page control tree are tightly coupled). If there were more controls after dummyLabel, their ViewState loading would fail.

To resolve this issue, all declarative Controls (defined in ASPX file) that should be removed, must be removed before ViewState loading takes place - in InitComplete event or any other event before it.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, seems odd.  I got it to work by moving your code that removes the control into the Page's `PreInit` event:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Request["remove-dummy"] != null)
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(this.dummyLabel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the workaround. Now I just need to know why this is happening. Why it works in Page_PreInit event and not in Page_Load event? I want this info in order to accept the answer, because this was my original question.

Comment: Well, per the documentation on the ASP.Net Page Event Life Cycle, `PreInit` is the place to deal with dynamic controls.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx  Other than that, I agree, I'd love to know more of the _why_.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with view state. Maybe by removing Control, view state gets serialized in some specific way so when it is deserialized into page and child control properties on next page load, it is unable to do so, because page contains one more control than it should, according to view state. Any thoughts on this suspicion? Is view state serialization so fragile?

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if maybe it was invalidating the ViewState.