# delete a submit button from ASP.NET form

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I have tried a `...Controls.Remove(ButtonToRemove)` from a bunch of containers including the `Page`, `NamingContainer`, and `Content` content placeholder control.  I have also tried setting the button Visible property to false, disabling the Button control, and setting the Text to an empty string.

Having tried all of those things and seeing the debugger run over the above described attempt code lines, and still seeing the button in question on the page when it shouldn't be, I am wondering if there is a browser rule that a submit button has to be visible no matter what.  I suspect that especially because a bunch of similarly deleted TextBox and Label controls are being correctly removed using the above methods.

This is the method I call from the Page_Load code the objects are defined as normal:

```
public void RemoveInputControls()
{
    LabelD.Text = string.Empty;
    LabelF.Text = string.Empty;
    LabelS.Text = string.Empty;
    TextBoxK.Visible = false;
    TextBoxK.ReadOnly = true;
    TextBoxK.Page.Controls.Remove(TextBoxK);
    TextBoxK.NamingContainer.Controls.Remove(TextBoxK);
    TextBoxK.Enabled = false;
    Content2.Controls.Remove(Content2.FindControl(TextBoxK.ID));
    Page.Controls.Remove(TextBoxK);

    ButtonSubmit.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
    ButtonSubmit.Text = string.Empty;
    ButtonSubmit.Visible = false;
    ButtonSubmit.Page.Controls.Remove(ButtonSubmit);
    ButtonSubmit.NamingContainer.Controls.Remove(ButtonSubmit);
    ButtonSubmit.Enabled = false;
    Content2.Controls.Remove(Content2.FindControl(ButtonSubmit.ID));
    Page.Controls.Remove(ButtonSubmit);
}
```

(sorry, I don't know how better to format asp.net markup for stackoverflow) and here is the page code, you can see it is a sub-page of a master page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="Index" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <div class="normal">
        <br />
        <h2><asp:Label ID="LabelD" runat="server" Text="Greetings!" CssClass="cssclass"></asp:Label>h2>
        <h4 class="cssh4"><asp:Label ID="LabelF" runat="server" Text="enter input:"></asp:Label></h4>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxK" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
        <h4 class="cssh4"><asp:Label ID="LabelS" runat="server" Text="click:"></asp:Label></h4>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit Input" Visible="true"/>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Share some code how is your button defined (markup) and how exactly did you try to remove it (code behind).

Comment: Still finding hard to help you, improve the question with more detailed description when do you want to remove the button/what is the event when you want it to happen (Page_Load? any other condition? ..add the whole code of Page_Load or whenever you call the `RemoveInputControls()` method).

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your remove code to the *PreInit* event.

All declarative Controls (defined in ASPX file) that should be removed, must be removed before ViewState loading takes place (in *InitComplete* event or any other event before it)

Check: [ASP.NET issue when removing Control on Page Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699770/asp-net-issue-when-removing-control-on-page-load)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

'thepirat000's answer is very_illuminating; ultimately my solution was to omit the controls in question from the aspx markup based on a flag set in page render cycle event.

still not clear what or where the `ObjectInstance.Controls.Remove()` method is for, probably more a different platform not ASP.NET